# Stuck on Encryption with a keyword

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python3.4.1. Any help would be appreciated

```
text = (str(input('Enter your message here, in upper case')))
key = (str(input('Enter the key word here, in upper case')))
for a in range (0,len(text),1):
    code = ord((text[a])+(ord(key[a%len(key)]))-64)
    if (text[a]==' '):
        print(' ', end= '')
    elif code > 90:
        print(chr(code + 26), end = '')
    else:
        print(chr(code), end = '')
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve and your problem.

Comment: I AM trying to encrypt a phrase using a key word

Comment: What problem are you facing with your code?

Comment: Have you considered using symmetric key encryption such as AES? Whatever letter swapping algorithm you are using can easily be cracked.